# How can I add a onclick event on an image created from js script?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to create an image from the javascript script, and to add a function when the said image is clicked.

```
let b = document.body;
let newIMG = document.createElement('img');
newIMG.src = 'img.jpg';
newIMG.onclick = 'clickImage()';
b.append(newIMG)

function clickImage() {
    console.log("clicked")
}
```

With the code I wrote, the image is properly created and displayed, but nothing happens when I click it and I can't understand why. Thank you for you help !

Comment: just as a further explanation: you are attempting to do something similar to when setting the onclick attribute of the html element. That's actually done differently `newIMG.setAttribute('onclick', 'clickImage()');`. While doing like suggested in the anwers, is like doing `.addEventListener('click', clickImage);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `onclick` to the function instead of a string.

```js
let b = document.body;
let js
newIMG = document.createElement('img');
newIMG.src = 'img.jpg';
newIMG.onclick = clickImage;
b.append(newIMG)

function clickImage() {
    console.log("clicked")
}
```